# Resigning textfield by clicking on other textfield in swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

i have three text fields. one is for showing date picker, second is to showing options for gender and another one is for showing country code. let say gender dropdown box is showing now, if i will click on dateofbirth or contrycode textfield, then gender will be hidden. like that if date of birth is showing and i will click gender or country code textfield , then date of birth textfield will be hidden. same will work for countrycode.

code for showing gender textfield:-

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool{

        if textField == gender_TextField{
            tableViewOne.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
                make.top.equalTo(textField.frame.maxY)
                make.left.equalTo(textField.frame.origin.x)
                make.right.equalTo(0-(self.containerView.frame.maxX-textField.frame.maxX))
                make.height.equalTo(0)
            }
            self.containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
            UIView .animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
                self.tableViewOne.snp.updateConstraints({ (make) -> Void in
                    make.height.equalTo(130)
                })
                self.containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
            
            if(textField == gender_TextField){
                self.selectedTextfeild = 1
                self.selectedTextFieldType = DROPDOWN_TEXTFIELD.gender
            }
            tableViewOne.tableFooterView = UIView()
            tableViewOne.reloadData()
            tableViewOne.isHidden = !isTableViewHiden
            isTableViewHiden = !isTableViewHiden
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
```

code for showing date picker

```
datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged(datePicker:)), for: .valueChanged)
       datePickerView.datePickerMode = .date
       dob_TextField.inputView = datePickerView
       datePickerView.maximumDate = Date()
```

code for showing countrycode

```
     countryPickerView.delegate = self
       if countryPickerView.selectedCountry.phoneCode != "+93"{
               
               countryCode_Lable.text = countryPickerView.selectedCountry.phoneCode

           }
           else{
               
               countryCode_Lable.text = "+1"

           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the other two views and can resign the other two textFields when one is active.